# Use t-statistics to measure between group differences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, standard-deviation, group-differences

I have read a paper [(https://doi.org/10.1038/s41591-023-02296-6)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41591-023-02296-6)

in this paper, fig 5, the authors point out:

> between-group differences (disease versus health, t-statistics,
> **two-sided**) in body (n = 78, top) and brain (n = 2,309, bottom) features (x axis)

My question is:

1. It seems to be rare to use the t statistic to measure the difference between groups. Compared with other similar statistics, such as Z-score, does it have any advantages?
2. The author mentions the t-statistic and mentions that it is two-sided, how is this different from the two-sided t-statistic threshold used for significance testing?

Comment: Are you aware of the two-sample t-test? This is not "rare" but standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test Note that the t-test takes into account that the variance is not known but estimated; a standard z-test wouldn't do that.

Comment: However, just looking at Fig. 5, the description is somewhat confusing. Particularly I'd have thought that for just plotting the value of the t-statistic it doesn't matter whether they test one- or two-sided.

Comment: @ Christian Hennig，no, I am aware that they try to use t statistic (not t-test) to measure difference, when t stastic is large, they think the differece between two group is large

Comment: The t-test is based on the t-statistic though. It measures the difference between group means standardised by its estimated standard error. (A corresponding z-statistic would do the same thing by the way, and would lead to a more or less equivalent plot, depending on how exactly the standard error is estimated.)

Comment: yeah, It seems that z-score is a more common practice (correctly?), so I would like to compare whether there are any special considerations when choosing t-statistics here, although they are essentially normalized variations

Comment: Well, people may even refer to the same thing as t- or z-statistic (the t refers to the distribution used for testing; if you only give the statistics value, this doesn't play a role). As far as I'm aware, there is nothing nonstandard or unusual about using t here.

Comment: Ok, I got that, thank you for your detail answer.